# Grouping dictionaries using Pandas DataFrae from two separate lists

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have two pickle files, each of which is a dictionary of satellite images with their date, PM value, and location of sensor. They have the following setup:

```
{'Image': array([[[...]]], dtype=uint8),
 'Date' : '2018-01-01',
 'PM' : 100,
 'Location' : 'Los Angeles'}
```

This is ONE input into the dictionary, i.e., if my pickle is called `data`, then `data[10]` would be the entry for Jan 09, 2018, such as:

```
{'Image': array([[[...]]], dtype=uint8),
 'Date' : '2018-01-09',
 'PM' : 19,
 'Location' : 'Los Angeles'}
```

I want to combine two pickle files, with lengths 1079 and 1023 respectively, into ONE pickle file grouped by the location. So after pairing, when I call `data[0]`, I get the 1079 inputs for the first sensor station, and `data[1]` will be the 1023 inputs for the second sensor station. The second sensor station is located in San Diego, and has the exact same format as the first station in terms of its dictionary.

Here's what I have:

I read in both pickle files using the following code (ran this code twice w/ different pickle files, so now i have two lists)

```
LA_data=[]
with open('/work/srs108/LA/data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                try:
                    LA_data.append(pkl.load(f))
                except EOFError:
                    break

SD_data=[]
with open('/work/srs108/SD/data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                try:
                    SD_data.append(pkl.load(f))
                except EOFError:
                    break
```

But now I have two lists, and I'm struggling using the following line to convert it to a Pandas dataframe in order to use the groupby function. I don't know what dimensions to give because my data are lists of dictionary inputs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(??,??), columns = ['Image', 'Date', 'PM', 'Location'])
```

Any tips on how to get my dictionaries into a dataframe in order to group them together? Is this the right way I should go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify "data" as variable? In case it is like "city_list" in this small rebuild, this might work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr1 = np.array([[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]]])
dict1 = {'Image': arr1,
         'Date' : '2018-01-01',
         'PM' : 100,
         'Location' : 'Los Angeles'}
LA_data=[dict1]

arr2 = np.array([[[11], [12]], [[13], [14]]])
dict2 = {'Image': arr2,
         'Date' : '2018-01-09',
         'PM' : 19,
         'Location' : 'San Diego'}
SD_data=[dict2]
city_list = LA_data + SD_data

df = pd.DataFrame(city_list)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Okay, this seemed to work! Now i have one dataframe, next how would I go about grouping it by 'Location', such that i only have two instances, one for each sensor location?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by instances? A row in the dataframe is already an instance or do you wanna split that row somehow?

Comment: Sorry, i think i'm too new to python to understand the correct definition of instance. Following your answer, I want to try to use `df = df.groupby(['Location'])`, but the resultant dataframe doesn't have any attributes such as df.iloc, or df.to_pickle.

Comment: I didn't have a definition of instance in mind either, to group the dataframe you could define some metric, but in case of `Location` maybe use some alphabetical grouping like when applying with `df.sort_values('Location')`